# Rename converted Excel File AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck in a situation where I had to rename my excel file.

Scenario:

I have converted Table into excel file,  that part I have successfully done , problem is when I downloaded the file it download as :"Download.xls" I want to rename it "MYExcel.xls".

**app.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-link col-md-2" ng-click="exportToExcel('#tableToExport1')">Export</button>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
    var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
    console.log(location.href)

    $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
}
```

**Excel.service.js**

```
 .factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},

            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                    console.log(ctx)
                return href;
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to leverage the `download` attribute of an [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

It specifies the filename to be downloaded.

```
//old
$timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
//new
$timeout(function(){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href=exportHref;
    a.download = "MYExcel.xls";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
},100);
```

In the old days, the file would have been served by a server, and the headers sent with it would give out the download rule, and the filename. Since you are serving the file directly from the client, there is no way to define this header (no HTTP request is made) so we need to play tricks. Here I've added an anchor tag to the body, trigger a click to start the download, and remove it. You might want to add styling to it to make sure we don't see it on the page.

Comment: saying corrupted if I use xlsx

Comment: xls and xlsx are 2 very different file formats. Make sure to use the extension that fits with the file you are generating.